# Is it dangerous to use a memorystream as a private field

Tags: c#, security

Is it dangerous to use a memorystream as a private field in an instance class?

The class implements IDisposable:

```
class MyIDisposableClass:IDisposable{
private MemoryStream _stream;


//do stuff with _stream


void Dispose(){
_stream.Close();
_stream.Dispose();//does this statement make sense here ?
}
}
```

and will be used like this:

```
using(MyIDisposableClass() bla=new MyIDisposableClass())
{...}
```

Is that good approach or should I do something else, to give all class member access to that kind of information?

Comment: You probably want to implement `Dispose(bool)` too. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're fine as long as you are wrapping your object in a using**

After the using block the object's disposed method will get called. As long as you clean up everything you'll be fine.

And if you are worried about **when it will be called** the code here will show  you.

```
using System;

public class DisposableExample : IDisposable
{

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before Disposing");
        using(var disposableObj = new DisposableExample())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Using Statement");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After Disposing");
    }
}
```

This will print out

```
Before Disposing
Inside Using Statement
Disposed
After Disposing
```

See fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h7hNPh)